# Configure a Twiml Bin to a Twilio number using PHP

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, twilio-twiml

How can we configure a `Twiml` Bin to a `Twilio` number using PHP (Laravel)? I am able to buy a number, but I can't figure out how to assign a `Twiml` Bin to a number that we have bought.

I am able to manually configure it from the Twilio Console.

**Twilio Console:**
[image]

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Adding to what A-Developer-Has-No-Name said, while you can [configure the Voice URL of a phone number on the fly](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers?code-sample=code-update-an-incomingphonenumber&code-language=php&code-sdk-version=5.x) using the REST API, there is no API for TwiML Bins so you can't create or edit those on the fly.

If you just have a set of static TwiML Bins that you want to toggle a phone numbers Voice URL between you can get the URL of each TwiML Bin by opening up the TwiML Bin from the [TwiML Bins section](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/twiml-bins) of the Twilio Console:

[image]

There you can see the Handler URL which you can copy and paste.

[image]

Once you have the URLs you can use the REST API to dynamically switch a phone numbers Voice URL to one of them.

Hop that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a response to the phone number is NOT configuration that can be done on the fly. You need to choose between configuring either a twiml response, webhook or Twilio function .that is done through the console.
If you would like to be able to make decisions at 'runtime' you can simply select webhook and add the URL that points to where you are hosting your PHP application
and responds with a redirect sending Twilio to the Twilio bin URL .
see : https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/redirect for the redirect response